# How to insert php ajax textbox value into mysql database table?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have ajax call in my index page, when the user enter a username into the text box it's need to insert into a mysql db table,can't find a way to do it?

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#enter_email_id').change(function () {  
var str = $('#enter_email_id').val();
var webFormURL = "get_acc_info.php?q=" + str;
    $.ajax({
    url: webFormURL,
    async: false,
   success: function (response) {
    $('.test_acc').html(response);
}   
});
```

This is insert db php page

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["username"];

function insert_Details(){
    include 'Db_Connection.php';

    $sql="INSERT INTO search(searcher,searched_time,searched_email)
    VALUES('$_SESSION[username]',".NOW().",'$_POST[searched_email]')";
} 
?>
```

Comment: change $_POST[searched_email] to $_GET[q]

Comment: What @devpro says works. The code you're showing is completely UNSAFE, though. Make sure you refactor it and build in some checks to see if $_GET['q'] even exists. And take a look at PHP's `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: any one can insert anything by using ajax request and GET param..... open for SQL injection.

Comment: now() is a mysql function not a php function. use date('Y-m-d H:i:s') or change the sql to:
... VALUES('$_SESSION[username]',NOW(),'$_POST[searched_email]')";

Comment: @devpro,@CaptainCarl Thank you so much,  I have an auto increment column named ID in my db table, Do I need to include it in my insert php sql query?

Comment: no problem, but plz tell me, issue has been resolved by changing $_POST[searched_email] to $_GET[q]

Comment: first of all tell, what r u using mysql or mysqli???

Answer (score 1):

for **security** reasons you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for input values.
I've got to fix your code, but you should replace `$_SESSION["username"]` value with what you want, use this code:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#enter_email_id').change(function () {  
var str = $('#enter_email_id').val();
var webFormURL = "get_acc_info.php?q=" + str;
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: webFormURL,
    async: false,
   success: function (response) {
    $('.test_acc').html(response);
}   
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$_SESSION["username"] = 'test_username';

function insert_Details(){
    //create mysqli connection
    include 'Db_Connection.php';

    $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_link,$_POST[searched_email]);
    $session = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_link,$_SESSION[username]);
    $sql="INSERT INTO search(searcher,searched_time,searched_email)
    VALUES('$session',NOW(),'$string')";

  if(mysqli_query($mysqli_link,$sql) ) {
   echo "OK";
  }
} 
?>
```

Comment: @devpro tell me more my bro

Comment: mysqli_query, mysqli_real_escape_string u need link identifier in both functions

Comment: secondly, use quotes '$session',NOW(),'$string'

Comment: mysqli_query, mysqli_real_escape_string u need link identifier in both functions

Comment: `$_POST` should be `$_GET` also, since he is using AJAX

Comment: Also change the method as GET or use data param in ajax.. Any way vote for mysqli

Comment: how we can use this without mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: @devpro why not? you can access $_GET['q'] from php code!